# Error running WSGI application AttributeError: module 'juzgado10_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi' has no attribute 'application', how do i fix this?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy a web app I've made in wagtail on pythonanywhere and i keep bumping into errors and issues and its a nightmare honestly, apparently its a wsgi issue but i have no clue how to solve it.

Here's my WSGI configuration file.

```py
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
"""
WSGI config for juzgado10 project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
#
## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/juzgado10/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/juzgado10/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/juzgado10/pagina-juzgado/juzgado10'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'juzgado10.settings.prod'
#
## then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
app = get_wsgi_application()
```

And here's the error I get.

```
2023-04-17 10:06:11,483: Error running WSGI application
2023-04-17 10:06:11,484: AttributeError: module 'juzgado10_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi' has no attribute 'application'
2023-04-17 10:06:11,484: ***************************************************
2023-04-17 10:06:11,485: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2023-04-17 10:06:11,485: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2023-04-17 10:06:11,485: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2023-04-17 10:06:11,485: ***************************************************
2023-04-17 10:06:12,005: Error running WSGI application
2023-04-17 10:06:12,005: AttributeError: module 'juzgado10_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi' has no attribute 'application'
```

Comment: See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/